# How to use define in objective c in another define

Tags: objective-c

I need to use define inside another define to make code simple by replacing only at one place.
Problem (Objective C code)

```
#define URL @"www.example.com/"
#define UserLogin @"<Login xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/\"><Email>%@</Email><Password>%@</Password></Login>" 
.
.
.
#define UserRegistration @"<Reg xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/\"><Email>%@</Email></Reg>"
```

I am having a list of statements like this can I use URL at the place of xmlns=\".../\"
can I use the above defined URL like xmlns=\"URL/\"
so I can replace url at only at one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can in the following way --

```
#define URL @"www.example.com/"
#define UrlWithUrl [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Login xmlns=\"http://%@/\">",URL]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `#define` token will be expanded in a subsequent `#define` *provided* it is not in a string – in your case you wish to use `URL` in a string so just writing in the string will not result in it being expanded.

However in (Objective-)C adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated by the compiler to become a single string literal, e.g.:

```
@"one " @"two"
```

is transformed by the compiler into:

```
@"one two"
```

Knowing that you can rewrite your definition of `UserLogin` as *three* strings which will be joined by the compiler into one:

```
#define UserLogin @"<Login xmlns=\"" URL @"\"><Email>%@</Email><Password>%@</Password></Login>"
```

and a use of `UserLogin` in your code will be replaced by the three strings which are then joined by the compiler, e.g.

```
NSLog("%@", UserLogin);
```

becomes after preprocessing:

```
NSLog("%@", @"<Login xmlns=\"" @"www.example.com/" @"\"><Email>%@</Email><Password>%@</Password></Login>");
```

and then the adjacent string literals are joined:

```
NSLog("%@", @"<Login xmlns=\"www.example.com/\"><Email>%@</Email><Password>%@</Password></Login>");
```

For more complex cases you will need to read up on the [preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/cpp/Macros.html#Macros), in particular [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/cpp/Stringification.html)

In Xcode you can see the results of your macros by selecting the menu item `Product:Perform Action:Preprocess "..."`, this opens a window showing your source file after all the macros have been expanded, i.e. the resultant source code the compiler will compile.

HTH